# Drupal 6 - is node_submit() needed when saving node?

Tags: drupal-6, saving-data

I'm trying to fix problem in some legacy code which is generating nodes of custom content type "show", but only if node in same type and with same title doesn't exist already. Code looks like:

```
        $program = node_load(array('title' => $xml_node->program_title, 'type' => 'show'));
        if (!$program) {
          $program = new stdClass();
          $program->type = 'show';
...
          node_submit($program);
          node_save($program);
        }
```

So, script is first trying to load node in 'show' content type with specific title and if it fails it creates one.

Problem is, when it's called multiple times in short period of time (inside a loop) it creates double nodes. Like 2 shows with the same title created in same second?!?

What can be the problem there?

I was looking examples for how to save node in Drupal 6. In some they don't even call node_submit() . Is that call needed? If so, do I maybe have to pass to node_save() what  node_submit() returned? Or maybe node_load() fails to load existing node for some reason? Maybe some cache has to be cleared or something?

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83277/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-node-submit-before-node-save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know and used node_save to create nodes programmaticly there is no need for the node_submit() function.
The reason that double nodes are created is that the node_load() function fired before completing the updates to the node_load() cache. Try to add:

```
node_load(FALSE, NULL, TRUE);
```

after node_save($program).
this will clear the node_load() cache.

see:
https://api.drupal.org/comment/12084#comment-12084

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83277/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-node-submit-before-node-save